# ASP.NET's Entity Framework and Eager/Lazy Loading on User Model

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, model

I have a question about Entity Framework's loading behavior. In my ASP.NET MVC5 application, there is an ApplicationUser model, UserProfile model(for basic profile information such as name, address, gender etc), and UserContactProfile, UserEducationProfile, UserJobProfile models(for secondary information not usually needed).

In this relationship, ApplicationUser owns a UserProfile, while UserProfile owns a UserContactProfile, UserEducationProfile and UserJobProfile. The issue is that I want ApplicationUser to always eager load UserProfile, but UserProfile to lazy load sub-profiles such as UserContactProfile. How is this possible?

I've tried writing some kind of code, while this does not seem to work:

```
var user = Db.Users.Find(Id);
```

The one below actually does the trick:

```
var user = Db.Users.Include(u => u.Profile).Where(u => u.Id == userId).First();
```

The idea is that I want the eager/lazy loading behaviors to be automatic, so even the first code that did not work before will pull User and UserProfile information. How is this achievable? I heard that editing ApplicationDbContext's onModelBinding() method may work, but I havent found a way yet.

Comment: you have to explicitly set `LazyLoading` to `true`.

Comment: Well right now my problem is that eager loading is not working, since when I load User model it wont load UserProfile.

Comment: can you show some code?

Comment: you need to declare `Virtual` properties for `LazyLoading`.

Comment: If you are eager loading entities, I find it helps to be explicit about that with include statements and setting the context objects lazy loading to be false.  This approach can help force the hand of your fellow developers to be conscious of query performance and object linking/fetching.

Comment: I see, yeah using include() statement explicitly will work. But what if it is an even inner nested model. For instance, in a post model I want to load the inner ApplicationUser model for post author. But I also want to further load the UserProfile Model, which is an inner model object for ApplicationUser. So the Post has an author(ApplicationUser), and ApplicationUser has a profile(UserProfile). How can I use an include statement to load the inner UserProfile model? It seems that I can only load the author, but not the inner profile, strange.